# Add leading 0 to mac address in bash

Tags: regex, bash, mac-address

I'm writing a script on bash to read MAC address from a group of devices and I'm stucked with one switch that returns address without leading 0. For instance:

0:A:B:11:22:C -> that would be -> 00:0A:0B:11:22:0C

Is there any way a regex could add these leading zeroes? I could take each address separately, take its bytes and adjust it, but I was wondering if there's an easier way.

Comment: Hi anishane. I've tried cutting the string into chunks delimited by ":", checking their size and adding a 0 in case it's 1; but I discarded this solution (too "heavy", and didn´t concatenate well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use sed. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character. So `\b\(\w\)\b` captures the substring which has a single word character.

```
sed 's/\b\(\w\)\b/0\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '0:A:B:11:22:C' | sed 's/\b\(\w\)\b/0\1/g'
00:0A:0B:11:22:0C
```

Comment: for more precise, you could use `sed 's/\b\([0-9A-Z]\)\b/0\1/g'`

Comment: Several comments regarding this somewhat bugulant code. (1) Hexadecimal does not use the letters G-Z, thus only A-F are relevant. (2) lower case hexadecimal characters are not accounted for. (3) This code seems not to function on the version of sed that is present on macOS based systems. That said (pun intended!), the first two issues can be addressed by substituting A-Z with A-Fa-f for full functionality. Moreover, on a macOS based instantiation of sed, this will work: echo '0:A:B:11:22:c' | sed -E 's/[[:<:]]([0-9A-Fa-f])[[:>:]]/0\1/g'

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do this in BASH itself using `read` and `printf` built-ins:

```
s='0:A:B:11:22:C'
IFS=: read -ra arr <<< "$s"
printf -v str "%02s:" "${arr[@]}"
echo "${str%:}"
00:0A:0B:11:22:0C
```